# How can I group by index with index +1 in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'index': [1, 2, 3, 69, 70, 71, 458, 459, 460],
                   'Animals': ['alligator', 'bee', 'falcon', 'lion',
                   'monkey', 'parrot', 'shark', 'whale', 'zebra'],})
df
```

Here is my DataFrame. I would like to `groupby` "index" column where first 3 animals which have index 1, 2, 3 goes to one group. The animals with numbers 69, 70, 71 goes to next group and so on.

In the end I would like to have 3 groups made by consecutive values in index column.

The good thing is the numbers in column index are always **+1** and then a gap larger than 1 but never just +1

It should be exist some function for that I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solutions for these invariably go for the compare to the previous row and cumsum the trues.

So perhaps something like this:

```
df['index'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, you want to group rows depending on whether difference is 1 or not right?. You can use `diff` + `ne` + `cumsum` to create different groups, `groupby` these groups and use `agg` to create lists:

```
out = df.groupby(df['index'].diff().ne(1).cumsum()).agg(list).reset_index(drop=True)
```

Output:

```
             index                   Animals
0        [1, 2, 3]  [alligator, bee, falcon]
1     [69, 70, 71]    [lion, monkey, parrot]
2  [458, 459, 460]     [shark, whale, zebra]
```